# Adding a PIT Id

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.3

I have a Postgresql 9.3 query that looks like:

```
select dateSoS, timeSoS
from workSchedules
where timeSoS between '02:00' and '11:00'
group by dateSoS, timeSoS, createdTs
order by dateSoS desc, createdTs desc, timeSoS desc;
```

It outputs about 10k records that look something like:

```
"2021-04-15";"08:00:00"
"2021-04-15";"08:00:00"
"2021-04-15";"08:00:00"
"2021-04-15";"08:00:00"
"2021-04-15";"08:00:00"
"2021-04-15";"07:30:00"
"2021-04-15";"07:30:00"
"2021-04-15";"07:30:00"
"2021-04-14";"07:30:00"
"2021-04-14";"07:30:00"
"2021-04-14";"07:30:00"
"2021-04-14";"07:30:00"
"2021-04-13";"06:30:00" <== not an error
"2021-04-13";"08:00:00"
"2021-04-13";"08:00:00"
"2021-04-13";"08:00:00"
...
```

Amongst which, workSchedules has an additional field called PITId (Point in Time Id). What I need is for PITId to be populated with a unique ID per date. In other words, using the above example, I want all records with a dateSoS of 2021-04-15 to have a PITId of 1, dateSoS of 2021-04-14 to have a PITId of 2, dateSoS of 2021-04-13 to have a PITId of 3, and ...

I tried writing a bit of PHP to do the job, but it runs for ever.

For the time range of timeSoS I also have four more ranges to run against. I don't mind running the query four times, but one run has to add the the previous.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Use `dense_rank()`:

```
select t.*,
       dense_rank() over (order by dateSos::date desc) as pitid
from t;
```

In an update, you can instead use:

```
update t
    set pitid = tt.new_pitid
    from (select dateSos::date as dateSos,
                 row_number() over (order by dateSos::date) as new_pitid
          from t
          group by 1
         ) tt
    where tt.dateSos = dateSos::date
```

Comment: Thank you. This is interesing. I didn't know about dense_rank (). Although your solution works, I'm not too sure how to apply it to an update stmnt.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up. Since my last comment I created something similar: UPDATE workSchedules SET PITId = sq.PITId
FROM  (select recId, dense_rank() over (order by dateSos::date desc) as pitid
from workSchedules
where timeSoS between '02:00' and '11:00'
order by dateSoS desc, recId desc, timeSoS desc ) AS sq
WHERE  workSchedules.recId = sq.recId.

Comment: The prob with the above is it doesn't allow for diff runs with diff timeSoS. So I created: DO $$
DECLARE myvar integer;
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_table;
    CREATE temporary TABLE tmp_table 
    (
 maxPITId int
    );
    insert into tmp_table (maxPITId) select max (PITId) from workSchedules;
END $$;
Looks too complicated, but works.